# How to have editable gridview

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-addin, data-view-web-part

I do have a table which have values like
ID Idea Creator etc..

Once clicked On ID it give a new page displaying details about that particular Idea.

Now the case is, there may be many Ideas by one single creator
and if he/she wants to edit few of his/her idea they need to click on every single entity and edit it inside.

Is there a way where I can create a page with the table showing detailed Ideas of a creator where he/she can edit multiple ideas at once (Like editable table).

Sorry if you find this question unstructured or invalid as I am new to this and learning.

Thanks in advance.